# Django: Checks with web-view

Tags: python, django, health-monitoring

I read the docs for checks: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/checks/

I am missing something: I would like to have a web view where an admin can see what's wrong.

Calling this view should execute the check and the result (ok or failure messages) should be visible.

I could hack something like this myself.

But I would like to go a common way, if there is already such a way.

As opposed to unit-testing this is about checking a **production** server.

How to do this the django-way?

Examples for checks I have on my mind: Checking if third party services are available (smtp server, archive systems, ERP systems, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin system check is mainly for development actually - the point is that if those tests fail your project will very probably not run at all.

But you can nonetheless call this (or any other) management command from python code using `management.call_command` - you'll just need to provide a writable file-like object to capture stdout/stderr:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from django.core.management import call_command, check

def check_view(request):
    out = StringIO()
    cmd = check.Command(stdout=out, stderr=out)
    call_command(check)
    out.seek(0)
    context = {"results": out.readlines()}
    return render(request, "check.html", context)
```

Then it's just a matter of plugin this into your admin (which is documented so I won't give a complete example).

NB : wrt/ adding your own checks to the `check` command, [this is fully documented too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/checks/#writing-your-own-checks).

Answer (score 1):

Cloud platform providers often provide health checks that ping your app at a certain point eg: /health

[django-health-check](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-health-check) provides tests that could be executed when /health is accessed.

If they all pass it returns a 200. Otherwise the cloud provider will notify your admins.

Of course you could make that page only visible for admins to manually check or write your own script to supervise your application status.